# Springboot with Javascript and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a filter page in springboot that works fine. When I add my javascript to the html page to make a query using an .change event listener, I want to use this query to live show available results before submitting the form. It looks like this (shorter version, otherwise its just var declaration that's not part of the problem)

```
$("#leadsForm").change(function () {
    //revenue
    var revMin = document.getElementById("revenueMin").value
    var revMax = document.getElementById("revenueMax").value

    //reg date
    var regDateMin = document.getElementById("regDateMin").value
    var regDateMax = document.getElementById("regDateMax").value

    var mainBranch = $('#mainBranch').val();
    var specificBranch = $('#specificBranch').val();

    var county = $('#county').val();

    var tel = document.getElementById("containsTel").value
    var contactPerson = document.getElementById("containsContactPerson").checked
    var location = document.getElementById("containsLocation").checked
    var employed = document.getElementById("containsEmployed").checked
    var keyValues = document.getElementById("containsKeyValues").checked
    var email = document.getElementById("containsEmail").checked
    var website = document.getElementById("containsWebsite").checked
    
var wholeQuery = "SELECT "+selectedColumns + " from company" + " WHERE " + revenueSelector + 
    regDateSelector + branchSelector +
        countySelector + telSelector + keyValuesSelector + contactPersonSelector + emailSelector +
        websiteSelector + locationSelector + employedSelector;

    console.log(wholeQuery)
```

I want to find a way to use this query, JAVASCRIPT SIDE to make the available result change on the .change eventlistener based on userinput, variables above in my variable "wholeQuery".

I use the code

```
const mysql = require((["mysql"]))
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "*****",
    password: "*****",
    database: "mydb"
})
console.log(db)
```

but get the Error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Script error for "mysql"
    https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
        at makeError (require.js:5)
        at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

The problem is that I can't connect to my SQL database through Javascript, is there any other way than the one above? I'm doing the solution most other threads recommend but its not working in my case because my project is not a node.js project.

Comment: Can you make the problem statement more clear?

Comment: Don't forget to introduce validation and escaping of the query! Any HTML element can be manipulated by a malicious user.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little confused, why connect directly to MySQL in the javascript? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a API call in Springboot that the js side talks to to get this? Judging by your code fragment you have a node.js project of some sort [like this one](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp)?

If you are using Springboot, I think you need to create a API that talks to MySQL, so your javascript will call the API (using something like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) maybe?)

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a good sollution for me. The reason why i wanted to connect it to my javascript was because i thought it was the easiest way (probably not). I will try making an api to retrive information. Thanks!

Comment: The API will be far more secure and could possibly be utilized by other products in the future. Your flow will look something like this: mysql > springboot(with jdbc or hikari driver talking to mysql >  front end node js project with something like Axios making api call to the spring boot service.